# Navigation bar on click reloads page

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table like this

```
Blood Inventory Stocks
Blood Component         Remarks
-----------------------------------------------
450ml Whole Blood        Released
350ml Whole Blood
```

and i would like to output those component who's remarks is not equal to Released. and so the expected output is the 350ml Whole Blood. But my query is wrong. This is my query.

```
        $data = BloodInventoryStocks::where('bloodtype', $bloodtype)
                        ->where('component','450ml Whole Blood')
                        ->orWhere('component', '350ml Whole Blood')
                        ->where('remarks','!=','Released')
                        ->get();
```

The result of my query is still the 450 and 350ml Blood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps, this is what you are looking for:

```
$data = BloodInventoryStocks::where('bloodtype', $bloodtype)
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('component','450ml Whole Blood')
            ->orWhere('component', '350ml Whole Blood');
            })
        ->where('remarks','!=','Released')
        ->get();
```

The way you were querying with `orWhere` before was breaking your query up and saying it is either what matches before this or after this.